# How do I see the iptables logs in systemd

Tags: iptables, logs, systemd

I have a system with Debian Jessie. It comes with systemd. I want to see the kernel logs for iptables.

I have a bunch of iptables and at the end I want to log what doesn't get allowed. I do it like this:

`iptables -A INPUT -j LOG`

With syslog I could see the iptables logs doing this:
 `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep kernel`
With systemd I can't find a way to see what is failing. I've been trying `journalctl` and `journalctl -f`.
journalctl alone shows a lot, doing a grep -v of what I am not interested I still can't see anything about iptables.

I also tried what is supposed to show kernel messages but I see nothing but when it started logging:

`journalctl  -k`

I am trying to find out if iptables is a service or what, but I can't see it with:

`systemctl --full list-units --type=service`

I tried following this post about systemd and logs in general, but I still get no clue about how can I see iptables logs: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs

Any hints ? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian Jessie does not remove syslog support by default. The old way (grepping through logs) should still work.

If you somehow accidentally removed syslog yourself, reinstall it:

```
apt install rsyslog
```

Comment: Thank you Wouter, that was a good starting point. It was a fresh Jessie install and it comes with no rsyslog by default. After installing it I do see some logs, ie ssh connections. But I still get no iptables logs. To make sure I just wrote a single rule: `iptables -A INPUT -j LOG`. I don't know what to try now.

Comment: Note that kernel logs are written to `kern.log` by default. Did you check that file?

Comment: Yes, I did `tail -f messages auth.log syslog kern.log`

Comment: Did you figure out the solution to this? I'm facing the same problem, on a Debian Jessie box as well.

Comment: @kai I did not. It still show no logs from iptables. I have other jessie servers and those work fine. The only difference is this one is inside an LXC container, so I think I can blame it to something related to LXC.

Answer (score 3):

`iptables -j LOG` is logged to kernel. look for`IN=` and `OUT=` in either `kernel.log` (if systemd logs to drive) or in `journalctl -k`, probably `dmesg` will list them as well. Example:

```
journalctl -k | grep "IN=.*OUT=.*" | less
```

Comment: My kernel log is empty. It just shows when it began, nothing else: # journalctl -k
-- Logs begin at dv 2016-09-02 13:51:34 CEST, end at dv 2016-09-23 12:39:01 CEST

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with log-levels: 
`journalctl -k --priority=[0-7]` or add `--log-level=[0-7]` to after your `-j LOG` to iptables, or both and you will definetly know on which level to search for those logs.